# Mongoid relation with a pre-defined object model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Here's my use case:

I've got a collection full of sales tax rates that have been imported from CSV files.  I created the Mongoid model to mirror the field names (these are not changeable):

```
class SalesTaxRate
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :state, type: String
  field :zip_code, type: String
  field :tax_region_name, type: String
  field :tax_region_code, type: String
  field :combined_rate, type: Float
end
```

Next, I'm building a model for use in my app.  Let's say I want to create something called a Location:

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :street, type: String
  field :city, type: String
  field :state, type: String
  field :zip_code, type: String
end
```

I'd like to be able to get a location's sales tax rate simply by calling something like this:

```
home = new Location(...)
home.sales_tax_rate
```

I'll never be setting the rate via `home`, just looking it up.

What's the "right" way to do this?  I can think of two approaches -- the simple way seems to be just to define a method that does the lookup, as so:

```
class Location
  ...
  def sales_tax_rate
     SalesTaxRate.where(zip_code: self.zip_code).first.combined_rate
  end
```

And this works.  But I'm wondering whether I should be using a `belongs_to` association and, if so, why and how best to do that.

Still learning the ropes here, so apologies if this is a novice/silly question.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on `zip_code` in model `SalesTaxRate` what you are doing is essentially the same as what `belongs_to` will do. Just have a nil check in your code to ensure that it doesn't fail:

```
SalesTaxRate.where(zip_code: self.zip_code).first.try(:combined_rate)
# or
rate = SalesTaxRate.where(zip_code: self.zip_code).first
rate.nil? ? nil : rate.combined_rate
```

If you still want to go `belongs_to` route, you can define `zip_code` to be the identity in your `SalesTaxRate`. But you should take care of few things if you do that: First, all the zip codes in imported data need to be unique. Second, your location model can not have any zip code which is not available in `SalesTaxRate` otherwise you will face issues.

Comment: Interesting - thanks!  So it seems that in this case, a simple lookup method is actually a more straightforward way of doing it considering I don't have direct control over the sales_tax_rate source data to enforce uniqueness or completeness.  And thank you for the tip on nil checking - that's good.